# Does the function get_Range allow for ranges outside the current sheet?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I was wondering whether someone encountered this before, suppose we have the following piece of code:

```
Excel.Range vl_range = (Excel.Range)((Excel.Worksheet)Application.ActiveSheet).get_Range("A1");
```

This safely returns the range of A1. However, if we input the string "'new sheet'!$C$1", then it gives a HRESULT error.

But, this can be solved by, the following piece of code:

```
Excel.Range vl_range = (Excel.Range)(Application.get_Range("'new sheet'!$C$1"));
```

That does seem to work. Now I was wondering if I input "A1" just in the last line of code, would it automatically assume that I'm referring to the active sheet?

Can someone explain to me, why this seems to be different in VBA? Where I can define ranges easily using the Range method, even though I am in a sheet?

Is my conclusion correct or am I making a horrible mistake somewhere?

Comment: In both the approaches you need to specify the sheet name (either by Application.ActiveSheet or in the string parameter) from which you want to get the range. If you want the 2nd approach to work without specifying the sheet name then you need to see how can you set the `Application.ActiveSheet` property before using the second approach without sheet name.

Comment: show the 'VBA way' that you're trying to mimic in C#, if that's the case

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who is interested. I have tested the code and if we use:

```
Excel.Range vl_range = (Excel.Range)(Application.get_Range("C1"));
```

Excel automatically assumes that you are referring to the Activesheet.